# Issue with Numpy brodcasting: implement "two-steps" broadcasting

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

I would like to compute a Fourier series like

[image: Fourier series]

(sorry had to copy a snapshot seems LaTex is not available on Stack Overflow), over a `np.meshgrid`.

Let us say I define some global variables

```
TERMS = 5
PERIOD = 1
A_0 = 1
c_nm = np.random.rand(TERMS,TERMS)
n_range = np.arange(0,TERMS, dtype = 'int')
m_range = np.arange(0,TERMS, dtype = 'int')
nn, mm = np.meshgrid(n_range, m_range)
```

and now, for **fixed**  `x`  and  `y` , I could compute the value of the series in one line

```
x = 0
y = 0
A_0 + (c_nm*np.sin(nn*x/PERIOD)*np.sin(nn*y/PERIOD)).sum()
```

the arrays  `c_nm`, `nn` and `mm` have all shape `(TERMS, TERMS)` and I think it works by "vectorising" over said matrices, before I take the sum.

But now, how to wrap this in a function that could vectorise a second time, over a  `x,y`   grid?

If I try

```
x = np.linspace(0,1,10)
y = np.linspace(0,1,10)
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x,y)
def fourier_series(x,y):
    return A_0 + (c_nm*np.sin(nn*x/PERIOD)*np.sin(nn*y/PERIOD)).sum()
```

and then try

```
fourier_series(xx,yy)
```

attempting to compute over the grid at once, I get the error (understandably)

```
operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (5,5) (10,10)
```

Now I think I see what is going on, but this is not of course what I am looking for.
The computation over the arrays  `c_nm`, `nn` and `mm` should be somehow done first, as an inner step, and only then the `fourier_series(xx,yy)` should operate on the `x,y`   grid.

Of course, I would also like not to have global variables such as `TERMS, nn, mm` lying around and I would like `TERMS` to be an input to the function and  `nn, mm` built internally, but I am stuck even before this.

Any hints please? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to compute 4 implicit nested rows. So you need 4 axes.

Pseudo code of what you want

```py
for y in np.linspace(0,1,10):
    for x in np.linspace(0,1,10):
        A[y,x] = A_0
        for n in range(TERMS):
            for m in range(TERMS):
                A[y,x] += c_nm*np.sin(nn*x/PERIOD)*np.sin(nn*y/PERIOD)
```

So, for that just decide which axis to use for each variable, and use broadcasting.

Note that there is no need of meshgrid for that (there is almost never a need for meshgrid; 95% of tutorials on internet that use meshgrid shouldn't. Broadcasting does the job. And with less memory and cpu usage most of the time).

```py
y=np.linspace(0,1,10)[:,None,None,None]
x=np.linspace(0,1,10)[None,:,None,None]
n=np.arange(TERMS)[None,None,:,None]
m=np.arange(TERMS)[None,None,None,:]
A=A_0 + (c_nm[None,None,:,:]*np.sin(m*x/PERIOD)*np.sin(n*y/PERIOD)).sum(axis=(2,3))
```

Note that here, if we had used `meshgrid` (which would be possible, just `meshgrid(y,x,n_range,m_range)` from your variables would create 4d-grids), then all intermediary result would have been 4d, and all intermediary computation would have been done in 4d.)
For example `m*x` would have been TERMS×TERMS×10×10 multiplication. When here, it is only TERMS×10 multiplications. Then TERMS×10 division by period instead of TERMS×TERMS×10×10. Then TERMS×10 sin. etc.

Likewise, in your single x,y working version, your usage of meshgrid for `nn` and `mm` means that `np.sin(nn*x/PERIOD)` computes TERMS² multiplication, then TERMS² divisions, then TERMS² sin. When they are redundant, since `nn` contains TERMS times the same thing.
With broadcasting, those operations are done only TERMS times (the strict minimum needed, for all TERMS different values). And int would be only when combining both `sin` and `cos` (for which there are TERMS² combinations of n and m values) that computations becomes 2D.

So, bottom line: you almost never need meshgrid. Each time you want to use meshgrid, ask yourself if you couldn't achieve the same result with broadcast. And almost always, the answer is "yes, and it reduces the computation and memory".

Comment: `meshgrid` with `indexing='ij'` and `sparse=True` creates arrays like your `None` expansions.  `np.,ix_` will to.

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks for pointing it out. I wasn't aware. That's good to know. It can be a more readable way to do the `[...None...]` thing indeed. That being said, I do not take back my rant against `meshgrid` :D : the 95% of tutorial I mentioned don't add that `indexing` and `sparse` option, and do create redundant memory and cpu usage :)

Comment: I'm perfectly happy with the `None` indexing.  By now it's second nature.  But I'm not sure what's clearest to beginners.

Answer (score 1):

Sticking with `meshgrid`, we can do the same broadcasting that @chrslg demonstrates.

```
In [1]: TERMS = 5
   ...: PERIOD = 1
   ...: A_0 = 1
   ...: c_nm = np.random.rand(TERMS,TERMS)
   ...: n_range = np.arange(0,TERMS, dtype = 'int')
   ...: m_range = np.arange(0,TERMS, dtype = 'int')
   ...: #nn, mm = np.meshgrid(n_range, m_range)
In [2]: x = np.linspace(0,1,10)
   ...: y = np.linspace(0,1,10)

In [4]: N,M,X,Y = np.meshgrid(n_range,m_range, x,y, indexing='ij',sparse=True)
```

See `meshgrid` docs for the meaning of the 2 added parameters.

```
In [6]: N.shape
Out[6]: (5, 1, 1, 1)
In [7]: X.shape
Out[7]: (1, 1, 10, 1)
```

These are the same shapes as produced by `[:,None,None,None]` etc.  Without `sparse`, `meshgrid` would produce `(5,5,10,10)` arrays, which will work in the same way.  `np.ix_` and `np.ogrid` can also be used to make arrays like this.

```
In [9]: res= A_0 + (c_nm*np.sin(N*X/PERIOD)*np.sin(M*Y/PERIOD)).sum(axis=(0,1))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[9], line 1
----> 1 res= A_0 + (c_nm*np.sin(N*X/PERIOD)*np.sin(M*Y/PERIOD)).sum(axis=(0,1))

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (5,5) (5,1,10,1)
```

`c_nm` has to be changed from (5,5) to (5,5,1,1)

```
In [10]: res= A_0 + (c_nm[:,:,None,None]*np.sin(N*X/PERIOD)*np.sin(M*Y/PERIOD)).sum(axis=(0,1))
In [11]: res.shape
Out[11]: (10, 10)
In [12]: res
Out[12]: 
array([[1.        , 1.        , 1.        , 1.        , 1.        ,
        1.        , 1.        , 1.        , 1.        , 1.        ],
       [1.        , 1.42259939, 1.80806583, 2.12420629, 2.34791282,
        2.4678581 , 2.48534036, 2.41319849, 2.27304808, 2.09136839],
        ...,
       [1.        , 1.51974465, 1.97830305, 2.32434701, 2.5245034 ,
        2.568257  , 2.46881994, 2.25987502, 1.98885895, 1.70807822]])
```

> Of course, I would also like not to have global variables such as TERMS, nn, mm lying around and I would like TERMS to be an input to the function and  nn, mm built internally, but I am stuck even before this.

To split things like this, you could make `x` and `y` to be (10,1) and (1,10) arrays (don't both have to be 10).  And in your function, define `c_nm`, `n`,`m` to be (TERMS,TERMS,1,1), (TERMS,1,1,1), and (1,TERMS,1,1) shaped.  `broadcasting` will automatically expand the `x` and `y` to (1,1,10,1) and (1,1,1,10).

With a little more housekeeping,`x` and `y` could have other dimensions. Some of that may be easier if the 2 `TERMS` dimensions were last,

Comment: thanks learnt a lot